# Append filename to CSV in new column

Tags: powershell, csv

I have a lot of csv files stored in a directory.
In each csv file need to add the name as column this through powershell.

**Example**

File location: `<SERVERNAME>\Export\FILENAME1.CSV`

Contents:

```
1232;Description;a1
1232;Description;a2
```

The result must be:

```
1232;Description;a1;FILENAME1.CSV
1232;Description;a2;FILENAME1.CSV
```

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: I did not quite understand the question. You have a lot of CSV files in a directory. Each CSV filename needs to appended by a column name. Which is this column name? is is the first column name? and you want to append the column name after the extension?

Comment: In the file needs the filename be added as column on each row of the file.
It's okay if it is the first or last column.

Comment: Please see [how to ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). What have you tried so far, and what errors/issues have you faced? StackOverflow is not a code-writing service. Ideally provide a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Okay. Now it is clear you just need to add a column with the filename. I will just revert back after testing. Meanwhile, does ur CSV have headers?

Comment: Do you want to have a single CSV file at the end, or just each individual file to have the additional column?

Comment: the single csv file do not have column names and do not have additional coumn.

Comment: in each csv file at the end of each row the filename exclude the extention.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following will append a Filename column to each .CSV file in a directory:

```
Get-ChildItem *.csv | ForEach-Object {
    $CSV = Import-CSV -Path $_.FullName -Delimiter ";"
    $FileName = $_.Name

    $CSV | Select-Object *,@{N='Filename';E={$FileName}} | Export-CSV $_.FullName -NTI -Delimiter ";"
}
```

**Explanation:**

- Uses `Get-ChildItem` to get all files named *.csv
- Iterates through each file with `ForEach-Object` and uses `Import-CSV` to load their contents as a PowerShell object
- Records the name of the file in `$FileName`
- Uses `Select-Object` to add a calculated property with the name `Filename` and the value of the `$FileName` variable
- Uses `Export-CSV` to write back over the original file. The `-NTI` (NoTypeInformation) switch is used to ensure the PowerShell object header line is not included.

Comment: Perfect answer. Judging by the preview the op shared, you might need to delimit the CSV manually. `import-csv $_.FullName -delimiter ";"`

Answer (score 2):

Mark Wragg's PowerShell code works, but I had to change the delimiter to , instead of ; so that it opens in Excel.  I'm trying to figure out how to append the filename to the first column instead of the last because my files don't have the same number of fields so they don't align.

Comment: how did u figure this out?